# How to remove a storage account from Azure through Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

When I run the Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount command in the Azure PowerShell task I get this error:

```
2019-01-24T13:07:29.0148404Z ==============================================================================
2019-01-24T13:07:29.0148533Z Task         : Azure PowerShell
2019-01-24T13:07:29.0148602Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
2019-01-24T13:07:29.0148688Z Version      : 3.1.18
2019-01-24T13:07:29.0148847Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-01-24T13:07:29.0148947Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613749)
2019-01-24T13:07:29.0149050Z ==============================================================================
2019-01-24T13:07:30.2233628Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\6.13.1\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
2019-01-24T13:07:42.1447157Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
2019-01-24T13:07:42.7204663Z ##[command]Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2019-01-24T13:07:43.0466903Z ##[command]Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
2019-01-24T13:07:44.1568578Z ##[command] Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId XXXXX -TenantId ***
2019-01-24T13:07:44.5546953Z ##[command]& 'D:\a\_temp\XXXXX.ps1' 
2019-01-24T13:07:44.6950579Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process
2019-01-24T13:07:45.1149833Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
2019-01-24T13:07:45.5569262Z ##[error]Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.
```

[image: Run a PowerShell script within the Azure environment]

This is the script I run:

```
Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount `
    -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupName" `
    -AccountName "mystorageaccountname"
    -Force
```

Note that I can create the storage account and the blob container in the same way without errors. This script works without any errors:

```
if(Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name "mystorageaccountname")
{
  New-AzureRmStorageAccount `
    -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupName" `
    -AccountName "mystorageaccountname" `
    -Location "West Europe" `
    -SkuName "Standard_LRS"

  New-AzureRmStorageContainer `
    -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupName" `
    -AccountName "mystorageaccountname" `
    -ContainerName "my-blob-container" `
    -PublicAccess "Blob"
}
```

How do I get the remove to work without errors through the Azure DevOps pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that happens because its asking to confirm deletion (`##[error]Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available`), you are missing: `.

```
Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount `
    -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupName" `
    -AccountName "mystorageaccountname" ` <<<<< here
    -Force
```

just retested it, it works without prompts if you supply `-Force`

Comment: Oh, good catch, now I feel a little stupid, I must have missed that when I added the -Force flag. I'll test and confirm it before I accept.

Comment: yeah, i've had mistakes worse ;) its fine